# How to read remote image into memory?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, base64, fs

I must read image file into memory on Firebase Cloud Function so I can convert to base64. But I get error:

> ```
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory
> ```

```
// Read the file into memory.
const fs = require('fs');
const imageFile = fs.readFileSync('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Lower_Manhattan_skyline_-_June_2017.jpg');

// Convert the image data to a Buffer and base64 encode it.
const encoded = Buffer.from(imageFile).toString('base64');
```

How I can read remote image file into memory?

Comment: It is 404 because it checks on the filesystem as you are using readFileSync.  Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch or https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios.

Comment: @kg99 Thanks for reply! So how I can do with axios? You can give example?

Comment: @kg99 I am try this but I not know how to store in variable and convert to base64 `axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: url,
  responseType: 'stream'
})
  .then(function (response) {
    response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('ada_lovelace.jpg'))
  });`

Comment: try axios({ method: 'get', url: url, responseType: 'stream' })
.then(function(response) { const encoded = Buffer.from(response.data).toString('base64'); });

Comment: @kg99 Thanks for reply! I try but it give error: `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type object `

Comment: I can see that you are dealing with another problem right now, it will be better to create new question with current problem.

Comment: @vitooh Thanks for reply! I have this problem now: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64969703/10654377. You can help?