# How to download image into local storage?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, fs, google-cloud-vision

I am use Node.js Firebase Cloud Function but need get image I have store in Firebase Storage so I can send to Google Cloud vision API.

[Vision API require](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-safe-search#vision_safe_search_detection-nodejs) send from local image file:

```
// const fileName = 'Local image file, e.g. /path/to/image.png';
// Performs safe search detection on the local file
const [result] = await client.safeSearchDetection(fileName);
const detections = result.safeSearchAnnotation;
```

How to download remote image into local storage?

For example I want store this image in local storage:

```
  const image = await axios.get(imgUrl)
```

Comment: Why don't you send a remote image path instead? https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-safe-search#explicit_content_detection_on_a_remote_image

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for reply!! I was do this and it work before (for 5 month). But today the API is throw error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'adult' of null` when I call `const data = await client.safeSearchDetection(
    remoteUrl
  );
  const safeSearch = data[0].safeSearchAnnotation; safeSearch.adult ...`. So I thought maybe because I was use remoteUrl. But maybe Cloud vision API is down?

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for help!

Comment: @DougStevenson You know how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you save to filesystem https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback , remember the name to get later. Something like:

```
const image = await axios.get(imgUrl);
const path = '/home/some/path/somefilename.jpg'
fs.writeFile(path, image, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw (err);
    }
    // save filepath to wherever for later.
    
});
```

Comment: Make sure to use image.data in the fs.writeFile call